# WlanQueryInterface fails inexplicably

Tags: c#, pinvoke, wifi

I've been beating my head on this for a while now.  A seemingly simple command in WLan is failing for me.  I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
[DllImport("Wlanapi.dll", EntryPoint = "WlanQueryInterface", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint WlanQueryInterface(
    [In] IntPtr hClientHandle, 
    [In] ref Guid pInterfaceGuid,
    WLAN_INTF_OPCODE OpCode, 
    IntPtr pReserved,
    [Out] out uint pdwDataSize, 
    ref IntPtr ppData,
    IntPtr pWlanOpcodeValueType);

var tempID = InterfaceID;
UInt32 dataSize;
IntPtr pData = IntPtr.Zero;

uint results = WlanQueryInterface(
    _sessionHandle, 
    ref tempID, 
    WLAN_INTF_OPCODE.wlan_intf_opcode_current_connection,
    IntPtr.Zero, 
    out dataSize, 
    ref pData, 
    IntPtr.Zero);
```

What I get back each and every time is a result of 50 and and no pointer. I have searched and have been unable to determine what 50 means as a return value. My best guess is it's ERROR_INVALID_STATE. But I also haven't been able to find any definitions for the error states that the documentation lists.

I've previously opened a handle and verified this is still valid. I've also verified that the Interface Guid is correct (in this case retrieved from the InterfaceInfo struct).  I'm using a lot of various WLan methods with no similar issues, so I'm guessing I have improperly defined the P/Invoke declaration.

If anyone sees the errors in my ways, I swear I'll change!

Comment: It is ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED.  It can't do it.

Comment: Thanks that answers one question. Where did you get that definition? And any idea why it cannot?

Comment: Error codes are listed in the WinError.h SDK header file.  And no, error_not_supported when I know nothing about your hardware and os.